# get long name during annotate in django ORM query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I have this model:

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    RANK_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('O', 'Officer'),
        ('E', 'Enlisted'),
        ('V', 'Civilian'),
        ('C', 'Cadet'),
    )
    ShortName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LongName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RANK_TYPE_CHOICES, default='O')
    Genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Career = models.ForeignKey(Career, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Photos, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

when I perform this ORM action:
   `models.Rank.objects.values('Type').annotate(total=Count('Type')).order_by()`

I get this response
    `<QuerySet [{'Type': 'O', 'total': 1}]>`

Exactly as I want.
However, as you can see, it gives me the short type.  How do I make it show the long name instead of the type choice short name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the values manually.

```
rank_dict = dict(RANK_TYPE_CHOICES)
for obj in my_ranks:
    obj['full_type'] = rank_dict[obj['Type']]
```

Comment: thanks much!  I'm going to give you the check here because this does work.  however, my issue bacame more than I thought.  I added another question for the expanded issue.  Thanks!